# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when using bootstrap js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-ui-bootstrap, webstorm

Here is the code of my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app">


    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/controllers.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, it shows the error in return:

> bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

[image: bootstrap_error]

Is it the problem of my code or bootstrap? I found the error exists when I add

```
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

into the `index.html`. Does anyone know the cause of the error? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked inside the files? Is there something wrong with them?

Comment: Your webserver is most likely returning a default error message, which is in html. Probably a 404.

Comment: Can you download the JS files by the given URLs using a browser? I think @tcooc is right. That's a HTML response from the server.

Comment: You say "it shows an error".  What is showing an error?  When is this error shown?  If it is your development environment, you can probably safely configure your development environment to ignore this error.

Comment: Thanks you guys, it is the problem of bootstrap.min.js. A whole set of HTML is stored inside the js while the bootstrap is retrieved from bower....

Comment: cdn site blocked in my concern. Any other way to get this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definitely a problem with the bootstrap file. The line 1 contains '<'.

Try manually opening the files and removing it.

Comment: Thanks!! I checked the bootstrap file and found that the index.html code is saved inside...I am now using bootstrap CDN link instead of bootstrap installed from bower and it is now solved. Although I still cannot figure out why index.html code will be saved inside the bootstrap.min.js while it is retrieved from bower...

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue with the ASP.Net. All I had to do is to clean the solution and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Discord discussion: Working with Bootstrap, Angular, React, Vue

The problem occurs because `sirv public --single` decides to send `index.html` for any route/resource that doesn't exist in the public directory - Issue with Routing.

You'll know right away that you have a problem when you are requesting, say, an image and you get back `200 text/html` response instead of a `404`.

The browser will try to parse the **index.html content** as though it were an image (or script in the case of this bug) and barf out. Even worse is that the cache is now polluted with garbage data for that URL and the only way to fix it is:

1. **Clear the cache or disable the cache completely.** as shown in the Chrome DevTools image below.
2. Fix any broken/unavailable routes in your Frontend App
3. Restart your Dev Server

Hope that helps... I know it drove me nuts for a while!

Answer (score -1):

It is because of files' addresses are not true, so make them correct. Based on my addresses:

```
 correct <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />
```

```
 wrong <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />
```

```
 correct  <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```
wrong <script src="/public/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```